# Component doesn't Update on Props Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This component doesn't update even tho props change.
prop `row` is an object.
`console.log("row", row")` does work. and get correct data also `console.log("Data", data)`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const Form = ({row}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(row);

  console.log("row", row); //consoleLog1

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(row);
  }, [row]);

  return (
    <>
      {Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).map((head) => {
        console.log("Data", data);//consoleLog2
        return <input type="text" name={head} defaultValue={data[head] == null ? "" : data[head]} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

**Update**

changing return to `<input value={data["ID"}>` . and it does update .
is there any way to create a form using looping object's properties?

Comment: `row` is not state, it's a prop, don't make it state. The Form component doesn't "own" row, therefore it's not state and trying to keep these values in sync will only make your head hurt and think, "why is React so hard?". React is not hard, you're just doing it wrong. This is a common mistake amongst people new (and even some not so new) to react.

Comment: It's not clear what's not working or what you're actually trying to do here

Comment: ```row``` is an object and  Im looping through its properties and getting property values and assigning them to a input

Comment: Yes, so what's not working? I'm guessing you want to update those properties (via on `onChange` listener on the inputs?) Take a look at the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: its only get data of first selected row . and it because of using defaultValue . (just learned via @Nicholas Tower) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaultValue` prop is used for uncontrolled components. It sets the starting value, and then it's out of your hands. All changes will be handled internally by `input`. So when you rerender and pass in a new defaultValue, that value is ignored.

If you need to change the value externally, then you either need to unmount and remount the components, which can be done by giving them a key which changes:

```
<input key={data[head].someUniqueIdThatChanged}
```

Or you need to use the input in a controlled manner, which means using the `value` prop instead.

```
value={data[head] == null ? "" : data[head]}
```

For more information on controlled vs uncontrolled components in react, see these pages:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

---

P.S, copying props into state is almost always a bad idea. Just use the prop directly:

```
const Form = ({row}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.getOwnPropertyNames(row).map((head) => {
        return <input type="text" name={head} defaultValue={row[head] == null ? "" : row[head]} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can I use another if statement to ```value``` to get input. and if so how ? . React Documentations are in Class type way... its kinda hard to follow for me  as Im new to React .

Comment: `Can I use another if statement to value to get input` I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: to assign values on each render and also get input from user.