# What is the equal code for OnChange on React Class Component , on React Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is the equal code for this on React Function Component without using defaultValue?

```
<input onChange((e)=>{this.setState({title : this.target.value})}) value={value} />
```

Comment: you can't use "this" in function components. See my answer below.

Comment: I also have a defualt value and im looping to create input component .

Comment: this is why i need this. if there better alternative ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69510795/component-doesnt-update-on-props-change .

Comment: you can set the state to the default value. I've updated my answer to show this

Comment: but for each input , i need a state that's a problem . and when defaultValue changes it doesn't seems to update .Sorry, what Im trying to do is click on a table row , open modal show Details , user can update details . so your answer only takes first row data .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your asking:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function MyComponent({defaultValue}) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        value={inputValue}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```